forcing to display null value if there is no record in the list part 2 minor bug
just want to follow up on my question here which was already answered
forcing to display null value if there is no record in the list
but later on i found a minor bug which i cant figure out.. i want to forced a data to display null value on the list of employee if filtered out by dates
my tables are
employee table
| emp_id | lastname | firstname |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  sgi01 | Doe      | John      |
|  sgi02 | Doe      | Karen     |  
|  sgi03 | Doe      | Vincent   |
|  sgi04 | Doe      | Kyle      | 
+--------+-------+--------------+

time_records table
| emp_id | date     |time_in  |time_out  |      
+--------+----------+---------|----------|
|  sgi01 |2024-03-02|07:00:00 |16:03:22  | 
|  sgi02 |2024-03-02|07:00:00 |16:03:22  |  
|  sgi03 |2024-03-01|07:00:00 |16:03:22  |
+--------+----------+---------+----------+

Result Table
| emp_id | lastname | firstname | time_in|time_out|Ctime_in   |Ctime_out  |number_of_hrs
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|  sgi01 | Doe      | John      |07:00:00+16:03:22|07:00:00 AM|04:03:22 PM|09:03:22
|  sgi02 | Doe      | Karen     |07:00:00+16:03:22|07:00:00 AM|04:03:22 PM|09:03:22    
|  sgi04 | Doe      | Kyle      |Null             |Null       |Null       |0
+-------+-----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+

Desired or want to display like this
    | emp_id | lastname | firstname | time_in|time_out|Ctime_in   |Ctime_out  |number_of_hrs
    +-------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
    |  sgi01 | Doe      | John      |07:00:00|16:03:22|07:00:00 AM|04:03:22 PM|09:03:22
    |  sgi02 | Doe      | Karen     |07:00:00|16:03:22|07:00:00 AM|04:03:22 PM|09:03:22    
    |  sgi03 | Doe      | Vincent   |Null    |Null    |Null       |Null       |0
    |  sgi04 | Doe      | Kyle      |Null    |Null    |Null       |Null       |0
    +-------+-----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+

MYSQL CODE
SELECT e.emp_id, e.lastname, e.firstname, T.time_in, t.time_out ,

TIME_FORMAT(time_in, "%r") as Ctime_in,

TIME_FORMAT(time_out, "%r") as Ctime_out,

TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in) as number_of_hrs

FROM `employees` as e LEFT JOIN time_records as t  on e.emp_id = t.emp_id
where t.date = '2024-03-02' OR t.date IS null \\this was answered from my previous post thanks credits to the one who answer
GROUP by e.emp_id;

since where clause with including date is null i was able to dislay null value if the employee never had any records of that date at all but the bug was if the employee has a different record or atleast has a record it never display the null value..

SELECT e.emp_id, e.lastname, e.firstname, T.time_in, t.time_out ,
TIME_FORMAT(time_in, "%r") as Ctime_in,
TIME_FORMAT(time_out, "%r") as Ctime_out,
TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in) as number_of_hrs
FROM `employee` as e LEFT JOIN time_records as t  
on e.emp_id = t.emp_id and t.date = '2024-03-02'

There is difference between WHERE clause and ON clause.
When a database returns records by connecting two or more tables, it generates an intermediate temporary table, which is then returned to the user.
The difference between the on and where conditions when using left join is as follows:

The on condition is a condition used when generating a temporary table, which returns records from the left table regardless of whether the condition in on is true or not.

The where condition is a condition that filters the temporary table after it is generated. At this point, there is no longer the meaning of left join (records in the left table must be returned), and if the condition is not true, all will be filtered out.


You can simply understand it as, when the filtering criteria are in 'on', first filter based on the filtering criteria, and then connect between tables. When the filtering criteria are in 'where', first connect the two tables and then filter.
you can refere this SQL JOIN: what is the difference between WHERE clause and ON clause?

thank you for elaborating, i didnt know that there is a difference between the two,i always thought combining where and on are almost the same thing, since i though left join will be the priority to render first

@RaymartCalinao The meaning in inner join is same, but differen in left join and right join
